# Using timer0 in PIC16F877A

Tags: microcontroller, pic, timer, assembly

I'm just starting out with timers on microcontrollers and part of my assignment requires me to write a value to timer0 in order for it to increment after a specified time. What confuses me is that I thought that the timer can either act as a timer/counter where the time taken for it to it to increment and overflow in timer mode is dependent mainly on the prescaler value. So why would one write a value to the timer0 register and would it be as simple as saying

MOVLW 0x20

MOVWF TMR0

Comment: Think about 'the time taken for it to it to increment and overflow' if you start it at a value which is not 0 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the datasheet at hand, but let's say you've setup the prescaler so that a full timer0-overflow (0xFF -> 0x00) occurs every 1 second.

Now let's say that, with the same setup, you want an interrupt every 0.5 second instead. What you do then is to preload the TMR0 register with 0x80. This way, it will have the first half second "already filled up", so to speak, and at every interrupt you just reload TMR0 with 0x80 again.

And yes, it's as simple as just movwf:ing into the register.